# how to set a variable as a property

Tags: javascript, dom

i'm looking for a way to set a variable as a property (for an element same as a div)
here is the code:

```
function set_it(element,property){
    return element.style.property;
}
console.log(set_it(document.getElementById("div1"),"left"));
```

at last line i'm trying to get "left" property of "div1" by the function 
**but I get undefined in console**
I know , actually it will look for a property named "property" , which doesn't exist
but how can I do this ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function set_it(element,property){
    return element.style[property];
}
```

Like so! You can use variables as object accessors when you use square brackets, not dot notation.